# It it possible to store stack's custom snaphot in a private github repository?

Tags: haskell, github, haskell-stack

Currenly I use

```
- resolver: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/blah-blah/stack-snapshot/10/snapshot.yaml
```

where `blah-blah` is a public repo. But once I make it private, it becomes something like

```
- resolver: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/blah-blah/stack-snapshot/10/snapshot.yaml?token=AJ_tHmg3nl_bW6LdG9DSgzIIKs0zqKICks2by0i4wA%3D%3D
```

I.e. there is an additional token. `stack` doesn't like this and doesn't pick up the snapshot.

Is there a way to make such a github link for a private repo that `stack` understands it and picks up the custom snapshot?